# javascript var and google maps api json

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-maps, maps

I want to show in the map the coordinates inserted in inputs. But I cant pass the values to the google map script

Here's the code.

```
<input type="text" id="latitude" class="form-control" />        
<input type="text" id="longitude" class="form-control"/>
<div id="myMap"></div>
<script>

var cx = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
var cy = document.getElementById("longitude").value;
  function initMap() {
    var ubication={lat : cy , lng : cx};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: ubication
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ubication,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

My problem is in `var ubication={lat : cy , lng : cx};`

My `API` key is correct also but I didn't include it for safety.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it, had to parseFloat() the string.